# High Stocks. Multi XAxis --- Month wise data not align with big amount of Data Points

Tags: highcharts

I was using these multipliers to display months and it actually works fine if I have less points but once I have a more points its just messed up the whole chart..Here is what happened I have 2 X-Axis 1) to display just dates while the other one which is opposite to that x-axis displays Month with Year. This is their requirement so I cant change.

Days wise I use to every other 3 days using (3*24*3600*1000) interval so it work but when I use (30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000) to display months it creates a mess. So let say I have March data point if I see bottom xaxis it looks fine but the month one is way off

I have tried almost all the possible solutions but nothing works out. Any Quick Help will be highly appreciable

Comment: Could you replicate your chart as live demo on the jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I don't know how could I do that, this chart is using following things like threshold with Spline,

Comment: <BR/>So basically I have created a control chart.that consist of 3 lines(3 JSON array)  one for current/historical data and that line split into two future lines so (2 different JSON array). Plus we are using thresholds as well

Comment: <BR/><BR/>So initially I tried using 3 json array and it works fine just to display line but not work with threshold and also display in Zoom bar at the bottom So to achieve that I have to create another Array which is a consolidated one so it creates only a points not line so this works out pretty well until I have less amount of data. And the issue where it failed is when I have 2 Axis and since I am using "linked to" property which kind of messing up one Xaxis no matter which interval I use

Comment: Does this description works out? to figure what the issue is?

Comment: We have no informaitona bout your jsons / data which you use, so we still are not able to replicate your issue.

Comment: ok here is the link sorry took a while some deadlines
http://jsfiddle.net/XebMax/9xptegdn/12/
On top of it trying to replicate it here .... 
So for the sake of simplicity I use same data on both Xaxis so check how both xaxis is different in month data and both are not got synched

Comment: I have already answer by email, but try to set the [ordinal](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal) parameter as false for xaxis.